# Variogram for a "gridded" data

Tags: r, grid

I have a gridded spatial 2d data,[my coordinates data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IYRC.png)

if i try

```
vB=variogram(z~1, data=as.data.frame(data))
```

i get the error:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘gridded’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you need a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` to use `variogram` function. So you have to convert your `data frame` first.

Assume your data frame has 3 columns `x`, `y` & `z`

```
data_sp <- data
coordinates(data_sp) = ~x + y
str(data_sp)
```